# iPhone UITextView scrollable but not editable

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uitextfield

How can I get a textview to be able to scroll without the keyboard poping up for edit when clicked on? I am pretty new to iPhone programming and I've tried several different combinations in Interface Builder, but can't seem to get any to work. Also I am having trouble when I have two textviews on the screen where only one of them will scroll. Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355720/how-to-disable-uitextfields-edit-property

Answer (score 9):

```
textView.editable=NO;
```

it is a property of UITextview, check the documentation

cheers

Answer (score 6):

In IB, next to the "Text Color" box, untick the 'Editable' checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> - (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
>     return NO;
> }
> ```

try to implement this UITextView's delegate method.

Comment: The easiest, the greatest and most obvious ;-) Thx