# How to disable UITextField's edit property?

Tags: ios, uikit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy way to disable a UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599733/easy-way-to-disable-a-uitextfield)

I have a UITextField. I want to disable its edit property. I just want to display a text in it.

How can i achieve it ?.

Comment: For displaying text you should use a UILabel not a UITextField (it is used for input some string)

Comment: I use `myTextField.enabled = false` for this.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

To disable editing in UITextField you need to return `NO` in delegate method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    return NO;
}
```

To disable editing in UITextView set property `editable` to `NO`:

```
[textView setEditable:NO];
```

Comment: if you are using UITextField don't forget to setup delegate in IB or through code `textField.delegate = self;`

Comment: The method is called `textViewShouldBeginEditing:` not `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`

Comment: @padde, textViewShouldBeginEditing - method for UITextView. We are talking about **UITextField**

Comment: [textView setEnabled:NO];

Comment: @DavidDouglas @Blasco73 `[textView setEnabled:NO];` disables the whole TextView, that's wrong. There is `editable` property which disables possibility to edit textview.

Comment: The question is about a textField not "View: