# Read Only UITextView on Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am new to Xcode and need some help with making a `UITextView`.

I would like to make multiple paragraphs in a `UITextView` that can scroll, but when it is tapped by the user, does not become editable.

The only solution that i could find was an outdated one for Xcode 2 so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable UITextField's edit property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355720/how-to-disable-uitextfields-edit-property)

Comment: Yes it seems you are correct, apologies, my son was using my account by mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Objective-C use:

```
yourTextView.editable = NO;
```

For Swift use:

```
yourTextView.editable = false
```

Comment: Hi, It was actually my son that wrote this on my account by mistake, he is very new to iOS development (last couple of days). Would you be able to tell us which file this line of code needs to go in please?  Thanks.

Comment: You can put it in `viewDidLoad` method. Or anywhere after you initialised the text view (if you create it programmatically).

Comment: Thanks, this makes much more sense now.  However he is using a UITextView and xcode 5 says .editable is not a property for that object type.

Comment: Are you sure he is using `UITextView`? editable is a property of `UITextView`. If he is using `UITextField` instead the property to set to `NO` is `userInteractionEnabled`.

Comment: There is no `editable` property on UITextField in iOS 8.

Comment: The OP is asking about UITextView.